# Socket.io > calling client-side functions from server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to execute functions on the client side from a node server using socket.io. The data is getting to the client side no problem but I am not able to execute functions on connect.

My server code (emit in a loop):

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(client){
    setInterval(function(){
        client.emit('for_client', datatosend);
    }, 100);
});
```

My client side code:

```
socket.on('for_client', function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    switch(true) {
        case (data == "reload"):
            console.log('DO reload');  //<<< not working
            break;

        case (data == "switch"):
            console.log('DO switch');  //<<< not working
            break;

        default:
            console.log(data);  //<<< this DOES work
    }

});
```

And here is proof the data is coming through ;)

[image]

Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: why you are using `setInterval` ??

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement is what's mucking it up.  You should have

```
switch(data) {
    case "reload":
        console.log('DO reload');
        break;

    case "switch":
        console.log('DO switch');
        break;

    default:
        console.log(data);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul .. I did try that. and still nothing. I do have a bit of a mix of datatypes in the data being received... the default switch are integers (as strings) and the reload/switch are obviously strings. Could I be getting into a type issue?

Comment: Your example doesn't match what you just described, can you update your example to be what your actual code is (or at least part of it)?

Answer (score 0):

```
//comparison operator in the switch " "==> it get the data as string  below method worked for me just normal comparison
switch(true) {
    case data == reload:
        console.log('DO reload');  //will work just test
        break;

    case data == switch:
        console.log('DO switch');  ///working
        break;

    default:
        console.log(data);  //<<< this DOES work
}
```